# running django-crontab inside virtualenv

Tags: python, django, cron

What is the correct way to run django-crontab inside a virtual environment?

I have created a cron task, added the task using 'python manage.py crontab add' and can see the task in my cron list. But the task is being executed under the user environment, as opposed to the virtual environment containing the django project.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you virtual ENV cmd -

```
python manage.py celery -A proj-name worker -l debug
```

Comment: I'm trying to get django-crontab working. celery is far too advanced for what I need.